# Flask-restful: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: python, flask, microsoft-graph-api, mime-types, flask-restful

```
Flask==2.3.3
Werkzeug==2.3.7
```

I'm trying to get a ms graph subscription going in my app but when I send the subscription request to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

and get the follow-up request from ms grap to my endpoint (ValidateSubscription), flask refuses to parse it because of its incorrect **mediatype** which is `text/plain`. So far I've tried using `flask-accept` module to parse the response like this:

```
class ValidateSubscription(Resource):
    @accept('text/plain')
    def post:
        if flask.request.args.get("validationToken"):
            token = flask.request.args.get('validationToken')
            return Response(status=200, mimetype='text/plain', response=token)
        else:
            # process notification
            pass
```

but it didn't work and I got the same error.

Also I've tried to add an **api representation** to my flask app like this:

```
@api.representation('text/plain')
def output_text(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = flask.make_response(data, code, headers)
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
    return resp
```

When I print out `api.representations` I see:

```
OrderedDict([('application/json', <function output_json at 0x7f872b021424>), ('text/plain', <function output_text at 0x7f8728d04214>)])
```

And I still get the same exact error without any change whatsoever.
Is there a better way to allow flask-restful to accept a `text/plain` header or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Been trying for 2 days and nothing really works, except rolling both `flask` and `werkzeug` versions back to 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution I found working is rolling `flask` and `Werkzeug` back to versions 2.0.0.

This is due to some commit in newer `Werkzeug` version that instead of sometimes throwing a, quote, "Poorly comprehendable error message" when `Content-Type` of the incoming request isn't `application/json`, simply throws 415 INCORRECT MEDIA TYPE error everytime this happens.